# True or False: After inserting '(2/3)m' elements into a hash table of size 'm', the probability of a collision upon the next insertion is at least 1/2

Tags: probability, logic, hash-function

I was asked this question today, and my initial thought was - let's check a numeric example.

So $m$ is obviously a multiple of $3$, and the smallest possible value is $m=3$.

I divided the sample space into disjoint events, and then calculated the probability for collision:

```
1st element is in entry #1, 2nd element is in entry 1; probability for collision is 1/3
1st element is in entry #1, 2nd element is in entry 2; probability for collision is 2/3
1st element is in entry #1, 2nd element is in entry 3; probability for collision is 2/3
1st element is in entry #2, 2nd element is in entry 1; probability for collision is 2/3
1st element is in entry #2, 2nd element is in entry 2; probability for collision is 1/3
1st element is in entry #2, 2nd element is in entry 3; probability for collision is 2/3
1st element is in entry #3, 2nd element is in entry 1; probability for collision is 2/3
1st element is in entry #3, 2nd element is in entry 2; probability for collision is 2/3
1st element is in entry #3, 2nd element is in entry 3; probability for collision is 1/3
```

Hence the overall probability is $(15/3)/9$, or simply $5/9$, which is of course larger than $1/2$.

I was hoping to get a counter-example, but damn...

Then, for $m=6$, the computation becomes much more complicated, and isince I had a good feeling that it would surpass $1/2$ as well, I've figured I may as well look for a proof rather than a counterexample (though calculating the probability for different values of $m$ may help in understanding the problem and perhaps finding a reason for why this statement is true).

However, it then struck me that this may well be a logical problem, or more precisely - a linguistic problem, where one has to fully understand what is being asked.

For example, I can interpret the question above as:

True or False: After inserting $(2/3)m$ elements into a hash table of size $m$, the probability of a collision upon the next insertion is at least $1/2$, **regardless of what hash function was used and what elements were inserted**.

Then, it is obvious that this statement is false, since there are cases where those $(2/3)m$ elements were inserted into a single entry, or more generally, into at most $(1/2)m$ entries.

In other words, if I show a single example where the probability of a collision is not larger than $0.5$, then the statement is false.

But it's really hard to tell what the intention of the author in this case, because if we ask "**what is the probability?**" instead of "**is it true that the probability is always larger than $1/2$?**", then the answer may well be some value larger than $1/2$.

My questions are:

1. Am I correct in my argument for why this statement is false?
2. Is there a way to determine a unilateral interpretation for this statement?

Thank you!!!

Comment: The probability depends on what elements did you insert before so it doesn't depend only on $m$.

Answer (score 1):

If the first $2m/3$ entries collide among themselves enough s.t. they occupy $<1/2$ the table, then the next insertion clearly collides with prob $<1/2$.  This is uninteresting, and so the original author cannot possibly mean "For any possible first $2m/3$ entries..."  If the first $2m/3$ entries don't collide, and fill up $2/3$ of the table, then the next insertion clearly collides with prob $=2/3 > 1/2$.  This is also uninteresting.

The interesting interpretation (IMHO) is what if the first $2m/3$ entries are also random and independent.  In this case, the next insertion collides with the $i$th previous entry with probability $1/m$, for $i \in \{1, 2, ..., 2m/3\}$, and all such potential collusions are independent (because the previous entries are independent).  Therefore, probability that the next insertion does NOT collide $= p_m = (1 - {1\over m})^{2m/3}$, and the claim is $p_m < 1/2$.

BTW for $m=3, p_m = (1 - 1/3)^2 = 4/9$ which agrees with your result (since my $p_m$ is prob of NOT colliding).

I dont know for what values of $m$ it is true that $p_m < 1/2$, but in the large $m$ limit this reduces to $p_m = ((1 - {1 \over m})^m)^{2/3} \approx (1/e)^{2/3} = e^{-2/3} \approx 0.513$.  Since this is the prob of NOT colliding, this interpretation of the claim is false for large $m$.